# Dynamic assignment of Q_Property variables

Tags: c++, qt, qml

So here is the situation

```
QQmlApplicationEngine* engine;
QQmlContext* ctxt;

class Fruit: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString type MEMBER m_type NOTIFY fruitChanged)

private:
    QString m_type;
public:
    virtual void initFruit() = 0;

    void startEating(){
        initFruit();
        ctxt->setContextProperty("fruit", this);
        engine->load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/qml/main.qml"))); 

       app.exec();
       engine->quit();
       engine->deleteLater();
    }

    void setType(QString fruit){
        m_type = fruit;
        emit fruitChanged();
    }
signals:
    fruitChanged();
};

class Apple:public Fruit{
public:
    explicit Appl(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    void initFruit(){
        Slice slice = new Slice();    // some other class
        ctxt->setContextProperty("slice", slice);
    }
};

class Banana:public Fruit{
public:
    explicit Banana(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    void initFruit(){
        Peel peel = new Peel();      // some other class
        ctxt->setContextProperty("peel", peel);
    }
};

class Peel: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString color MEMBER m_peelColor NOTIFY peelChanged)

private:
    QString m_peelColor;
signals:
    void peelChanged();
public:
    void someFunction(QString peelColor){
        m_peelColor = peelColor;
        emit peelChanged();
    }
}

class Slice: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int number MEMBER m_slices NOTIFY sliceChanged)

private:
    QString m_slices;
signals:
    void sliceChanged();
public:
    void someFunction(QString slices){
        m_slices = slices;
        emit sliceChanged();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    Fruit *fruit;

    if (argv[1] == "Apple"){
        fruit = new Apple();
    }
    else if (argv[1] == "Banana"){
        fruit = new Banana();
    }

    engine = new QQmlApplicationEngine();
    ctxt = engine->rootContext();

    fruit->setType(argv[1].toString());
    fruit->startEating();
}
```

Then in main.qml

```
...
Rectangle{
     Text {
        text: {    // I want to remove this if else statement
            if(fruit.type == "Apple")
                slice.number
            else if(fruit.type == "Banana") 
                peel.color
        }
    }
}
```

You can imagine how big my if-else statement in main.qml can get as I increase the number of fruits. So I am wondering if there is a different way of handling such a scenario where I can somehow just assign the text in qml one value and it dynamically loads the right back-end property.

Comment: Typo: change `emit fruitChanged;` to `emit fruitChanged();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of registering new data types in the initFruit method and using global variables it is better to create a provider class:

```cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

#include <cstring>

class Fruit: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    virtual Q_INVOKABLE QString name() = 0;
};
class Apple: public Fruit{
public:
    QString name(){
        return "apple";
    }
};
class Banana: public Fruit{
public:
    QString name(){
        return "banana";
    }
};
class FruitProvider: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(Fruit* fruit READ fruit WRITE setFruit NOTIFY fruitChanged)
public:
    FruitProvider(QObject *parent=nullptr):QObject(parent){}
    Fruit* fruit() const{
        return m_fruit.get();
    }
public slots:
    void setFruit(Fruit* fruit){
        m_fruit.reset(fruit);
        emit fruitChanged();
    }
Q_SIGNALS:
    void fruitChanged();
private:
    QScopedPointer<Fruit> m_fruit;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    FruitProvider provider;
    if(argc < 1){
        return -1;
    }
    if (std::strcmp(argv[1], "Apple") == 0){
        provider.setFruit(new Apple());
    }
    else if (std::strcmp(argv[1], "Banana") == 0){
        provider.setFruit(new Banana());
    }
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("provider", &provider);
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

```
Text{
    text: provider.fruit.name()
}
```

**Update:**

As I pointed out in the comments, the idea of eliminating if-elseif-else is to standardize access to properties, in the case of Fruit you can use provider. In the case of the "number" and "color" properties, you can create a generic property that is updated every time the other properties are modified and use that property to access the information in QML.

```cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>

#include <cstring>

class Peel: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString color MEMBER m_peelColor NOTIFY peelChanged)
private:
    QString m_peelColor;
signals:
    void peelChanged();
public:
    void someFunction(QString peelColor){
        m_peelColor = peelColor;
        emit peelChanged();
    }
};
class Slice: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(int number MEMBER m_slices NOTIFY sliceChanged)
private:
    int m_slices;
signals:
    void sliceChanged();
public:
    void someFunction(int slices){
        m_slices = slices;
        emit sliceChanged();
    }
};
class Fruit: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QVariant common MEMBER m_common NOTIFY commonChanged)
public:
    void startEating(){
        initFruit();
    }
    QVariant common() const{
        return m_common;
    }
Q_SIGNALS:
    void commonChanged();
protected:
    virtual void  initFruit() = 0;
    void setCommon(QVariant common){
        m_common = common;
        emit commonChanged();
    }
private:
    QVariant m_common;
};
class Apple: public Fruit{
public:
    void initFruit(){
        slice.reset(new Slice());
        slice->someFunction(100);

        setCommon(slice->property("number"));
        connect(slice.get(), &Slice::sliceChanged, [this](){
            setCommon(slice->property("number"));
        });
    }
private:
    QScopedPointer<Slice> slice;
};
class Banana: public Fruit{
public:
    void initFruit(){
        peel.reset(new Peel());
        peel->someFunction("red");
        setCommon(peel->property("color"));
        connect(peel.get(), &Peel::peelChanged, [this](){
            setCommon(peel->property("color"));
        });
    }
private:
    QScopedPointer<Peel> peel;
};
class FruitProvider: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(Fruit* fruit READ fruit WRITE setFruit NOTIFY fruitChanged)
public:
    Fruit* fruit() const{
        return m_fruit.get();
    }
public slots:
    void setFruit(Fruit* fruit){
        m_fruit.reset(fruit);
        emit fruitChanged();
    }
Q_SIGNALS:
    void fruitChanged();
private:
    QScopedPointer<Fruit> m_fruit;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    FruitProvider provider;
    if(argc < 1){
        return -1;
    }
    if (std::strcmp(argv[1], "Apple") == 0){
        provider.setFruit(new Apple());
    }
    else if (std::strcmp(argv[1], "Banana") == 0){
        provider.setFruit(new Banana());
    }

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("provider", &provider);
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    provider.fruit()->startEating();

    return app.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

```
Text{
    text: provider.fruit.common
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. But I still have a question. What about the Peel or Slice classes? What if I wanted the text to be peel.color if its a banana or slice.size if it's an apple? Only banana has peel and only apple has slice...

Comment: @Gebre According to your [MRE] slice and peel they have the same "something" attribute, now you point out that they have different "color" and "size" properties. The provider's idea can be scaled if the properties of the different types are the same. So if you want an answer for your new requirements then provide an MRE

Comment: @Gebre If you are going to use a different property for each type you will always have to use if-elseif-else to know the type and then call the appropriate method for each type, if the properties are common you can eliminate that if-elseif-else using the provider .

Comment: Ok, sorry for the confusion. That was my main problem that they have different properties. Thanks